# MySql error 1452

Tags: mysql

Возникает ошибка номер 1452. Как можно исправить?

Executing SQL script in server

```
ERROR: Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aptechniy_sklad3`.`zayavka`, CONSTRAINT `zayavka-zakupivlia1` FOREIGN KEY (`nomer_zayavku`) REFERENCES `zakupivlia` (`nomer_zayavku`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

SQL Code:

```
INSERT INTO `aptechniy_sklad3`.`zayavka` (`nomer_zayavku`, `data_skaladnnia`, `nomer apteku`, `data_vukonannia`) VALUES (100001, '2017-01-03', 0001, '2017-01-05')
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 40 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: Может вы пытаетесь добавить в поле значение внешнего ключа, которого не существует7

Comment: исправил, перепроверил все дание. ошибка дальше есть

Comment: Стоп. Что у вас является названием таблицы? aptechniy_sklad3?

Comment: aptechniy_sklad3 - бд . zayavka - таблица

Comment: Так название БД указывать не нужно. Только название таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

insert приводит к несогласованности данных, т.е. добавляемое вами в `zayavka`.`nomer_zayavku` значение равное 100001 отсутствует в `zakupivlia`.`nomer_zayavku`